# Union in query in C# code

Tags: c#, sql, union

I am trying to execute this query in C# code. But this generates some records which are not considering the one of the where clause in a query.

The result of the query is going to display in Grid. I am looking to add union and combine the result of those 2 queries in to one . Not sure how to do that.
I checked some examples but they contained just select queries and union. I am looking to use Union in my query which is like this

```
var query =
            (
                from dep in dTable.AsEnumerable()
                join stp in sTable.AsEnumerable()
                    on dep.Field<Decimal>("B_ID") equals stp.Field<Decimal>("G_B_NBR")
                join name in names.AsEnumerable()
                    on stp.Field<string>("LID") equals
                    name.Field<string>("lid") into outer
                from name in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join hd in HData.AsEnumerable()
                    on stp.Field<String>("LID") equals
                    hd.Field<String>("LID")
                     where (hd.Field<DateTime?>("G_CON_START") >= sd && hd.Field<DateTime?>("G_CON_START") <= ed)  ADD UNION HERE 
                      where (hd.Field<DateTime?>("G_CONT_SIG_DT") > hd.Field<DateTime?>("G_CONT_START") || hd.Field<DateTime?>("G_GANTACT_DT") > hd.Field<DateTime?>("G_CONT_START"))
                       where (hcmd.Field<DateTime?>("G_CONT_SIG_DT") > hd.Field<DateTime?>("G_CONT_START") || hd.Field<DateTime?>("G_GANTACT_DT") > hd.Field<DateTime?>("G_CONT_START"))
                       select
                new
                {


                    SId = stp.Field<String>("LID"),
                    FName = ((name == null) ? "" : name.Field<string>("first_name")),
                    LName = ((name == null) ? "" : name.Field<string>("last_name")),}).Distinct();
                    Grid.DataSource = query;
            Grid.DataBind();
```

Comment: What's stopping you from using a stored procedure for this?

Comment: Suggestion: If you can correctly write the SQL with desired results, then you can consider using *Dapper ORM*. Just add the Dapper NuGet, put your SQL, and easily your objects are populated. Sometimes it is more practical.

Comment: Creating any sql procedures in DB is out of scope of our projects

Comment: Can you add some samples of your tables and info? maybe this [tips for create a good sql-type question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/4092887) will help you.